# Called window is unresponsive?

Tags: java, keyevent

This bit of code calls two separate games when the respective key is pressed. the windows appear, but the user cannot play the game. The screen is unresponsive. How do i fix this?

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
    {

         if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_1)
           {
              //calls tic tac toe game, and point counter
              TicTacToe tic = new TicTacToe();
              TicTacToeDriver.main(null);
              PointCounter();
            }

          else if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_2)
           {
              //calls hanman game, and point counter
              Hangman hang = new Hangman();
              HangmanDriver.main(null);
              PointCounter();
           }
       }
```

Comment: this code doesn't help at all. It's extremely incomplete. A few general comments: you don't need to create an instance of a Class to access static methods. How do the subprograms even access the frame? I can't see any code sending a reference to the frame to the subroutines.

Comment: what other parts of the code would you need to see? I made this code with two other individuals. It is not methods being called, but two separate drivers.

Comment: Especially if the other two routines are individuals, the most likely reason they are unresponsive is the implementation of the other windows. Btw: are there any errors displayed in the console??

Answer (score 0):

An easier way to do what you want would be this, I think:

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

         if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_1) {
              //calls tic tac toe game, and point counter
              TicTacToeDriver.main(args);
              PointCounter();
            }

          else if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_2) {
              //calls hanman game, and point counter
              HangmanDriver.main(args);
              PointCounter();
           }
       }
```

Let me know if this works.

Comment: an error popped up "cannot find symbol - variable args"

Comment: Try adding this outside of the main class: private String[] args; Let me know if that works!

Comment: That's an answer to the question. You merely added a parameter - that apparently isn't required - to the driver-call and removed the useless instance-creations.